# JS: How to prevent default handling of middle click?

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

It seems like a ridiculous easy problem but it appears to be harder...

I want to **prevent the default handling of an middle click**. I created a JSFiddle and threw in `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatePropagation`, `preventDefault` and `return false` - like this:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "a", function(e)
{    
    console.log("\nprevent mousedown...");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("...mousedown prevented");
    return false;
});
```

But the middle-click is fired. BTW it is fired by the time I *release* the middle button. Here's the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Gq4p9/4/

Tested on Chrome 29, Firefox 23 and IE11.

I hope someone of you can find out, why this script doesn't prevent the default handling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, it works if you pass a **[jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)** as selector

```
$(document).on ("click", $("a"), function (e) { ...
```

though the [API](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  says `selector` is expected to be of type string.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T56Cj/3/)

---

Also you could always just use a plain javascript click eventListener.

```
link.addEventListener ("click", function (e) {
  if (e.which === 2) 
      e.preventDefault();
})
```

Heres a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Muz2p/)

Comment: Your solution works ... interesting. I now tired `$('a').bind("click",...)` and it works also. But shouldn't `$(document).on("click", "a",...)` work the same?

Comment: `$(document).on("click", function(e){...})` ***does*** prevent it, but `$(document).on("click", "a", function(e){...})` ***does not*** prevent it ... and this is what I don't quite understand. It seems in the latter variant the click event gets processed if the event *already bubbled up* to `document` and *then* it checks, if the selector matches the source item...

Comment: @Warappa It seems it doesn't get [triggered at all](http://jsfiddle.net/T56Cj/2/) when using the middle button, though it does with left button. 
Why don't you attach the listener directly to the elements, without using jQuery?

Comment: Arrrg, you're right: it wasn't trigged at all! The selector must be a ***full*** **jquery selector** -> `$("a")` - now it works http://jsfiddle.net/T56Cj/3/.  
If you include this in your answer I accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Warappa Hmm odd, where did you get that from? I would include it in the Answer, but the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is saying, `selector` should be of type `String`

Comment: This is what the fiddle told me ;) ... but seriously I think it's a kind of a bug.

Comment: @Warappa this seems to be indeed a bit buggy. If i find some more information i'll report it.

Comment: This solution only works if jQuery uses document as its base: jQuery(document).on If any other selector is used then it does not fire for middle clicks.

Comment: fwiw, using a jQuery object as the selector *doesn't* work, it just fires everywhere as if not using a selector at all. you can test testing `e.target` (or rather `$(e.target).closest('a')`) with .is() for your selector. Still doesn't prevent the new tab if the target is the link itself, but it works when clicking on a sub-element. weird.

Comment: Hmm, it only seems to work because I remove the link on middle click. And still some manage to slip though. oh well...

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem recently (actually the opposite: I wanted to only allow middle clicks to get through). The problem is that the behaviour you want to prevent is on the `click`, and preventing the default behaviour of `mousedown` does not necessarily prevent the default behaviour of ensuing events.

While the current solutions are perfectly correct, they won't work with IE8 and lower, because for those browsers the `click` event's `which` property always returns `0` no matter which button was used. So I wrote a jQuery plugin, **[jquery.whichclick](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/6592823)** to fire extra events: `leftclick`, `rightclick`, `middleclick` and `anyclick` — all of which report the correct `event.which` and all of which bind `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatePropagation` and `preventDefault` to the `click` event which follows.

Depending on the rest of your code, the plugin would allow you to use:

```
$( document ).on( 'middleclick', function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
} );
```

Or:

```
$( document ).on( 'anyclick', function( e ){
    if( e.which === 2 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        // Other conditions you may be looking for...
    }
} );
```

If you don't care about IE support though, this is overkill — just do what the other guys suggested!

Comment: Thanks for your insights! Fortunately I only must support IE9+. The problem though was not related to `which` but to the click event not being triggered (due to my wrong understanding of `on`.

Comment: « Fortunately I only must support IE9+ » there's no need to boast! ;)

Comment: I'm sorry for beeing tactless ;)

Comment: How did you allow the middle click to open a new link?  I'm having the same problem...

Comment: @DarianEverett just inverse the if/else condition in the last code snippet: prevent default if it's not type 2. Or if you don't want to prevent anything, just don't put any code in :)

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is this condition:

```
    if( e.which == 2 ) { 
        // prevent default behaviour
    }
```